# XNA GamePad Input Triggers Event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xna

I'm trying to use an xbox controller in WPF and I seem to have run into a problem.

I was able to grab the input from XNA using a gamepad

```
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.GamePadState currentState = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.GamePad.GetState(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.PlayerIndex.One);
```

but I can't figure out how to make WPF trigger the say "KeyPressed" event when something on the controller is pressed.

I tried doing some research but I couldn't find anything too specific or if I do they most of the time aren't answered. I found this below but it doesn't seem to answer how you could actually do this:

[Can you program buttons on a gamepad to bind with mouse/keybourd input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982446/can-you-program-buttons-on-a-gamepad-to-bind-with-mouse-keybourd-input)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to look at each of the buttons to see if they were pushed.

```
if (currentState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in another answer, you can check the state of the gamepad with:

```
if (currentState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
```

You can also use

```
if (currentState.IsButtonDown(Buttons.A))
```

You may want to create a dictionary of Buttons to Key mappings, but that is up to you.

Once you know how to check the gamepad state, your question reduces to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645815/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-keypress-events-in-c). See the accepted answer.